# (java) remove in iterator cannot be applied

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I am trying to remove some objects from a List while iterating over the list. To avoid, ConcurrentModificationException, I am using an Iterator and calling remove(). This part of the code looks like the following.

```
  Iterator<ClassName> it = classList.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        ClassName obj = it.next();
        if(obj.getData() == 1) {
            it.remove(obj);
        }
    }
```

I get the following error: remove() in java.util.Iterator cannot be applied to (ClassName). I have two questions

1. Why do I get this compilation error and how to fix it?
2. Is it a good practice (or even safe) to remove objects from a list while iterating over the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1. Why do I get this compilation error and how to fix it?*

Do `it.remove()` (and don't give it any arguments). The method will remove the current object from the underlying collection.

> *2. Is it a good practice (or even safe) to remove objects from a list while iterating over the list?*

Yes. This is a perfectly fine way to remove objects from a collection.

Comment: Thanks! I should have noticed!

Answer (score 0):

The method remove doesn't take any arguments , try

```
it.remove();
```

There is no harm in removing object while iterating from the List if you are using Iterator but calling directly `myList.remove(obj/index)` can result in [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Care should be taken when you are in multi-threaded environment.

Comment: You can get ConcurrentModificationExceptions in single threaded programs as well though.

Comment: @aioobe yes if we call list.remove() but OP is using iterator

Comment: Your answer seems to indicate that one does not need to be cautious in a single threaded environment, which is wrong.

Comment: @aioobe thanks i updated my answer ,hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You should call `remove()` in [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) which takes no arguments.

```
Iterator<ClassName> it = classList.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {
    ClassName obj = it.next();
    if(obj.getData() == 1) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Yes iterator is the way to remove object while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method of iterator which takes arguements as object.

```
 Iterator<ClassName> it = classList.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        ClassName obj = it.next();
        if(obj.getData() == 1) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

**Iterator.remove()** is safe.

Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

is from:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html

Answer (score 0):

Try **it.remove()** as mentioned by many Answers, and yes you can remove the objects and it is safe to remove while iterating over list.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get this compilation error and how to fix it?

You need not to pass an object to it. Current object will be remove directly. `it.remove()` is enough

> Is it a good practice (or even safe) to remove objects from a list while iterating over the list?

Yes. That is fine to iterate and remove an element from it. What not good practice/safe is **removing directly from list** object instead of iterator. When you try to remove from list directly and looping on it, that leads to `ConcurrentModificationException`.